# How can I make the clickable area size for my linkbutton to get bigger or related to the td cell atleast?

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

I want to increase the clickable area szie for my linkbutton, I am not using td cell to runat server so I can still apply the css when it is hovered. but if you will suggest that I need to make it to runat server, how can I still apply the css?

As of now, the only clickable linkbutton is the number, so if I clicked the spaces between the td cell it won't fire the linkbutton.

**CSS**

```
        #tablePager td:hover {
    background-color: #ff6600;
    }
```

***HTML***

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" PageSize="20" OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging"
                    AllowPaging="True" OnDataBound="GridView1_DataBound" 
                    Style="position: static"   >
                    <PagerSettings Position="Bottom" />
                    <PagerStyle ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Center" Font-Underline="False" CssClass="pager" />
                    <PagerTemplate>
                        <table id="tablePager">
                            <tr style="background-color: #F8F8F8;">
                                <td>
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="First" CommandName="Page" CommandArgument="First" runat="server"
                                        Text="&lt;&lt; First" Style="color: black" ForeColor="Black" Font-Underline="False"></asp:LinkButton>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="Previous" CommandName="Page" CommandArgument="Prev" runat="server"
                                        Text="&lt; Previous" Style="color: black" ForeColor="Black" Font-Underline="False"></asp:LinkButton>
                                </td>
                                <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" OnItemCommand="Repeater_ItemCommand" OnItemDataBound = "Repeater_ItemDataBound" OnLoad="Repeater_Load">
                                    <ItemTemplate>

                                        <td id="cell">
                                          <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkPageNumber" CommandName="Page" runat="server" ForeColor="Black" Font-Underline="False"/></linkbutton>        
                                        </td>

                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:Repeater>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="Next" CommandName="Page" CommandArgument="Next" runat="server"
                                        Text="Next &gt;" ForeColor="Black" Font-Underline="False"></asp:LinkButton>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="Last" CommandName="Page" CommandArgument="Last" runat="server"
                                        Text="Last &gt;&gt;" Style="color: black" ForeColor="Black" Font-Underline="False"></asp:LinkButton>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </PagerTemplate>
                </asp:GridView>
```

For now I couldn't capture my cursor on screenshot, and even if I recorded it on obs it won't capture cursor even if its on. so I just took the image from my cellphone.

[image]

**Rendered HTML**

```
    <div id="UpdatePanel1">

        <input type="submit" name="SortIdBtn" value="Sort Id (High)" id="SortIdBtn" />
        <input type="submit" name="SortAgeBtn" value="Sort Age (Low)" id="SortAgeBtn" />
            <br />

        <span id="Label1">Rows Count Result: </span>
        <span id="Label2">20</span>
        <span id="Label3"></span>
        <span id="Label4">(Total Results: 618)</span>
        <span id="Label5">Current Page Number: </span>
        <span id="Label6">1</span>
        <span id="Label7">out of 31</span>
        <div>
    <table cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="GridView1" style="border-collapse:collapse;position: static">
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Id</th><th scope="col">Name</th><th scope="col">Age</th><th scope="col">branch</th><th scope="col">date</th><th scope="col">time</th>
        </tr><tr>
            <td>1</td><td>Ismael</td><td>25</td><td>branch_1</td><td>0000-00-00</td><td>00:00:00</td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td>2</td><td>Dane</td><td>25</td><td>branch_2</td><td>0000-00-00</td><td>00:00:00</td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td>3</td><td>Allen</td><td>22</td><td>branch_3</td><td>2018-04-27</td><td>11:08:00</td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td>4</td><td>Test 1</td><td>12</td><td>branch_4</td><td>2018-04-21</td><td>01:00:00</td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td>5</td><td>Test 2</td><td>56</td><td>branch_5</td><td>0000-00-00</td><td>00:00:00</td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td>28</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>2018-04-27</td><td>01:00:00</td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td>27</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>2018-04-27</td><td>01:00:00</td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td>26</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>2018-04-27</td><td>01:00:00</td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td>25</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>2018-04-27</td><td>01:00:00</td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td>24</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>2018-04-28</td><td>01:00:00</td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td>23</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>2018-04-20</td><td>01:00:00</td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td>22</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>2018-04-20</td><td>01:00:00</td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td>29</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>2018-04-20</td><td>01:00:00</td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td>30</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>2018-04-20</td><td>01:00:00</td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td>31</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>2018-04-20</td><td>01:00:00</td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td>32</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>2018-04-20</td><td>01:00:00</td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td>33</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>2018-04-20</td><td>01:00:00</td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td>34</td><td>Ismael</td><td>25</td><td>branch_1</td><td>0000-00-00</td><td>00:00:00</td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td>35</td><td>Dane</td><td>25</td><td>branch_2</td><td>0000-00-00</td><td>00:00:00</td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td>36</td><td>Allen</td><td>24</td><td>branch_3</td><td>2018-04-27</td><td>01:00:00</td>
        </tr><tr class="pager" align="center" style="color:Black;text-decoration:none;">
            <td colspan="6">
                <table id="tablePager">
                    <tr style="background-color: #F8F8F8;">
                        <td>
                            <a id="GridView1_First" class="aspNetDisabled" style="color:Black;text-decoration:none;color:gray;cursor:default;"><< First</a>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <a id="GridView1_Previous" class="aspNetDisabled" style="color:Black;text-decoration:none;color:gray;cursor:default;">< Previous</a>
                        </td>


                                <td id="cell">
                                  <a id="GridView1_Repeater1_lnkPageNumber_0" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;GridView1$ctl23$Repeater1$ctl00$lnkPageNumber&#39;,&#39;&#39;)" style="color:Black;text-decoration:none;">1</a></linkbutton>        
                                </td>



                                <td id="cell">
                                  <a id="GridView1_Repeater1_lnkPageNumber_1" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;GridView1$ctl23$Repeater1$ctl01$lnkPageNumber&#39;,&#39;&#39;)" style="color:Black;text-decoration:none;">2</a></linkbutton>        
                                </td>



                                <td id="cell">
                                  <a id="GridView1_Repeater1_lnkPageNumber_2" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;GridView1$ctl23$Repeater1$ctl02$lnkPageNumber&#39;,&#39;&#39;)" style="color:Black;text-decoration:none;">3</a></linkbutton>        
                                </td>



                                <td id="cell">
                                  <a id="GridView1_Repeater1_lnkPageNumber_3" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;GridView1$ctl23$Repeater1$ctl03$lnkPageNumber&#39;,&#39;&#39;)" style="color:Black;text-decoration:none;">4</a></linkbutton>        
                                </td>



                                <td id="cell">
                                  <a id="GridView1_Repeater1_lnkPageNumber_4" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;GridView1$ctl23$Repeater1$ctl04$lnkPageNumber&#39;,&#39;&#39;)" style="color:Black;text-decoration:none;">5</a></linkbutton>        
                                </td>



                                <td id="cell">
                                  <a id="GridView1_Repeater1_lnkPageNumber_5" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;GridView1$ctl23$Repeater1$ctl05$lnkPageNumber&#39;,&#39;&#39;)" style="color:Black;text-decoration:none;">6</a></linkbutton>        
                                </td>



                                <td id="cell">
                                  <a id="GridView1_Repeater1_lnkPageNumber_6" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;GridView1$ctl23$Repeater1$ctl06$lnkPageNumber&#39;,&#39;&#39;)" style="color:Black;text-decoration:none;">7</a></linkbutton>        
                                </td>



                                <td id="cell">
                                  <a id="GridView1_Repeater1_lnkPageNumber_7" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;GridView1$ctl23$Repeater1$ctl07$lnkPageNumber&#39;,&#39;&#39;)" style="color:Black;text-decoration:none;">8</a></linkbutton>        
                                </td>



                                <td id="cell">
                                  <a id="GridView1_Repeater1_lnkPageNumber_8" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;GridView1$ctl23$Repeater1$ctl08$lnkPageNumber&#39;,&#39;&#39;)" style="color:Black;text-decoration:none;">9</a></linkbutton>        
                                </td>



                                <td id="cell">
                                  <a id="GridView1_Repeater1_lnkPageNumber_9" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;GridView1$ctl23$Repeater1$ctl09$lnkPageNumber&#39;,&#39;&#39;)" style="color:Black;text-decoration:none;">10</a></linkbutton>        
                                </td>


                        <td>
                            <a id="GridView1_Next" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;GridView1$ctl23$Next&#39;,&#39;&#39;)" style="color:Black;text-decoration:none;color:default;cursor:default;">Next ></a>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <a id="GridView1_Last" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;GridView1$ctl23$Last&#39;,&#39;&#39;)" style="color:Black;text-decoration:none;color:default;cursor:default;">Last >></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: We'd need the current **rendered** HTML & associated CSS.

Comment: @Paulie_D I updated it, please take a look

Comment: The HTML you provided is not the rendered/output version...we need that.

Comment: Like the html on the inspect element? is that what you mean?

Comment: @RanielQuirante either inspect element or view source.  Also, I don't think it is semantically correct for pagination to be in tables - perhaps they would be better in an ordered list?

Comment: @Pete So, instead of tables for pagination, I should convert it to ordered list? Can you give a bit of example on how can I apply that with my existing pagination?

Comment: I would do - tables are meant for tabular data only - I don't think pagination is tabular data.  [Here is an example ordered list](https://jsfiddle.net/p48gfs3o/)

Comment: okay, thanks pete I'll try applying this to my program, but I'll keep waiting for the answers so maybe I can apply the answers to my future projects.

Comment: anyways, I did made it to an ordered list and it works like a charm, thank you very much @Pete

Answer (score 0):

Either put your 'javascript: ....' code on the onclick event of the td element or maybe use this css code :

> td a {
>       display:block;
>       width:100%; }

didn't test it, tho